# How to read failed messages using Telephony class?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

Using telephony class,**Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI** shows the content uri of the message database, but using this content uri, it won't loop through the failed messages, it only shows inbox outbox sent messages. How can i access through the failed messages?

```
public void getAllSms() {
    Uri messageUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor c;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Sms Path : " + Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        c = cr.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Telephony.Sms.DATE + " DESC");
    } else {
        c = cr.query(messageUri, null, null, null, "date DESC");
    }

    this.startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = 0;
    if (c != null) {
        totalSMS = c.getCount();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalSMS; j++) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS));
                    String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.BODY));
                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.TYPE)).contains("1")) {
                        //      activities.setIsoutgoing(false);
                    } else if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.TYPE)).contains("5")) {
                        Log.d("Not inbox type", "Failed");
                    } else if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.TYPE)).contains("2")) {

                        Log.d("Not inbox type", "OUT");
                        // activities.setIsoutgoing(true);
                        //      activities.setActivitystatus("completed");
                    }
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } else {
        //   Toast.makeText(this, "No message to show!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Android version are you running on?

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: Marshmallow and the device is Samsung On7 pro.

Comment: Only the default messaging app can read the failed messages.

Comment: why? Can't we access that database records of failed messages?

Comment: I don't know why they decided to restrict that stuff, but regular apps can now only get the inbox and sent messages.